# What's the difference between pow and sqrt in this code?

Tags: mpu6050, gyroscope

I'm not the best at Arduino so I'm sorry for my "noobiness".

I'm extending some code that I found online to work on the gyroscope that I'm building.

I'm wondering what the difference is between `pow` and `sqrt` in this code.

I'm also wondering what the `180/pi` is used for. I haven't gotten my mind around this part yet.

```
arx = (180/3.141592) * atan(ax / pow((ay, 2) + pow(az, 2));
```

What's the difference here?

```
ary = (180/3.141592) * atan(ay / sqrt(square(ax, 2) + square(az, 2)));
```

Comment: `pow(x, 2) ` is the second power, so x² or x*x. `sqrt(x)` is the square root of x, so $\sqrt x$. A whole circle is 360 degrees or 2π when measuring in radians. So this ratio of `180/3.141592` is used to convert an angle in radians to an angle in degrees.

Comment: @Gerben That should be an answer, n'est pas?

Comment: @Gerben Do you know why im getting this error?                                                              In function 'void loop()':
error: too few arguments to function 'double pow(double, double)'
GettingValues:41: error: at this point in file
error: too many arguments to function 'double square(double)'
GettingValues:42: error: at this point in file
error: too many arguments to function 'double square(double)'

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. Change `pow((` to `pow(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting Gerben's comment into an answer:

---

pow(x, 2) is the second power, in other words:

[image: x squared]

---

sqrt(x) is the square root of x, that is:

[image: Square root of x]

---

A whole circle is 360 degrees or 2π when measuring in radians. So this ratio of `180 / 3.141592` is used to convert an angle in radians to an angle in degrees.

[image: radians to degrees]